# Image rendering chang while scale

Tags: html, css, image, css-animations, scale

This is an example of the page: [link](https://bucard.co.il/digitalCard/Github_Example-RRD)

My problem here is that the images rendering changes to be like "image-rendering: pixelated;" while the image is resized (when you hover some image), and when the resize over it changes back to normal.
(You can see this very clear when you hover Youtube for example)

I don't want it to be pixelated, and want the image rendering to be normal through all the mouse-hover.

This is my HTML (Made with React):

```
<li className="original-icon-li">
   <a href={props.hrefProp}>
      <img src={"/images/classicLogos/" + props.imageUrl} alt={props.imageUrl} />
   </a>
</li>
```

And the CSS:

```
.original-icon-li {
    margin: 10px;
    display: inline-block;
    transition: all .5s;
}

.original-icon-li a {
    padding: 5px;
    display: inline-block;
    border: none;
    transition: all .5s;
}

.original-icon-li a img {
    width: 90px;
    height: 90px;
    display: block;
    transition: all .5s;
}

.original-icon-li a:hover img {
    transform: scale(0.88);
}
```

What do you think is the problem ?

Comment: try add `-webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;` to your img

Comment: you could try `will-change: transform;` on `.original-icon-li a img`. This informs the browser that a change is about to take place which could help your issue. Best not to overuse this property on your page however because it can reduce performance.

Comment: most simple way would be to animate `width` and `height` instead of transform. Do not forget to compensate width loss of `a` element in that case

Comment: @Pepo_rasta this make the image always look pixalted, but I want to look smoother (like it looks when I don't hover)

Comment: @heatherhtml Same as above, the image is pixalted ^

Comment: @Pepo_rasta you mean something like this? : ```.original-icon-li a:hover img { animation: try-it-in .5s linear; }  .original-icon-li a:not(:hover) img { animation: try-it-out .5s linear; }  @keyframes try-it-in { to { width: 79px; height: 79px; } } @keyframes try-it-out { to { width: 90px; height: 90px; } }```